# Adding " into a string using str_c

Tags: r

I am trying to add a " into my code:

```
ddata = c("cook county, illinois", "the moon")
parameters = "&key=my-key"

apiRequests <- 
iconv(str_c('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json? 
address="', ddata[i] , parameters), "", "UTF-8")
```

The result of this is:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=\"cook county, illinois&key=my-key
```

I would like to obtain (I tried with using ' but it doesn't work, also, creating a separate string, but I think that is not the solution.)

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address="cook county, illinois"&key=my-key
```

Thank you,

Comment: try `"\""` instead of `""` the backslash escapes the quote which I think is what you need

Comment: @see24 It works but it is adding an extra character \. And when I try to execute the code, it doesn't work.